# How important is proper execution of QTEs in Fractured But Whole?

Tags: south-park-the-fractured-but-whole

I hate QTEs, especially if they are used as an integral aspect of combat. I've lost combat way more than I want in Stick of Truth because they introduced a new QTE and I couldn't figure out what to do in time.

I've started Fractured But Whole, played through until I started my origin story, immediately got faced with 2 QTEs and quit the game in disgust. Hell, even the "shitting in a toilet" minigame is something I never want to do ever again in this game if I can help it, because the keyboard controls are just horrendous.

However, I have a very morbid curiosity for the jokes and references in the game, so I want to continue playing. However, I'd prefer to avoid QTEs as much as possible, or at least only have to suffer those that are simple and don't have a big impact on my combat performance if I fail them. I'd preferably even avoid shitting in a toilet unless it's absolutely necessary to complete the game and all major sidequests (so no "shit in every toilet in the game").

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to shit in every toilet, I avoided 95% of them once I realized they were useless.

The QTE in the battle system enhance damage or status effects. You'll do extra damage for hard hitting moves, or inflict extra knockback, heal for more health, freeze enemies for 1 turn longer...etc.

You can certainly beat the game without nailing every single QTE, but they certainly help.

The ones that really matter are the ones with Mosquito who heals because the health gained was valuable I found. They were pretty easy too.

There are even some moves that are just a 1 time button press at the right time. I'd recommend finding the side kicks that have easier moves such as a single correct press or just mashing the X button for 2 seconds to achieve max damage.

The combat is much more focused on strategy than QTE performance, so you should be just fine.

Comment: Are the toilets really useless? One loading tool tip asks whether I have taken a shit in every toilet yet. On the other hand, it suggested that I should attack Morgen Freeman...

Comment: @Exa Completely useless except for 1 achievement. Gameplay wise it is completely useless.